# How to create a recursive binary tree in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a (generic) binary tree in TypeScript.

I've created an interface which looks like:

```js
interface Node<T> {
    (left?: T): Node<T>,
    (right?: T): Node<T>,
    (data: T): T
}
```

However, when I do this I get an error message which tells me that "all declarations of 'Node' must have identical type parameters.

Is it possible to create such structures in TypeScript or would I need to do this some other way?

An implementation made without generics appears to work fine.

```js
interface Node {
  left: Node,
  right: Node,
  data: any
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for this (I've used `TreeNode` rather than `Node` to avoid DOM conflicts):

```
interface TreeNode<T> {
    left?: TreeNode<T>;
    right?: TreeNode<T>;
    data: T;
}
```

Here's an example using it ([on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQhAcgewCYQA8qAfMgN4BQyNyANhDGAPwBcaG2%20RpA3NbSjAA5gAsW7dJlwFiJfrWR44YOJP4BfSpQZhkYTpM4yiAZwOhhZALwUBNZavYAiAEbOANPfqMw7KoqKjmrIznDO3hpeikJifnaBtMEuCBGKWhr8lAg4IKY4DAB0dDjCABQGmIXBAJS8iTQA9I2h7tm5%20UUl5ZUQxb7M1SpwdU0tYRE5eQV93RWchbHig7X1zaGplEA)):

```
let tree: TreeNode<string> = {
    data: "b",
    left: {
        data: "a"
    },
    right: {
        data: "c"
    }
};

console.log(tree.data);        // "b"
console.log(tree.left?.data);  // "a"
console.log(tree.right?.data); // "c"
```